# how can i add button Fragments,ViewPager using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I want to add a button (id='Home') which take me to the main activity i use those codes but it is not reacting, this is a sample of my project in GITHUB please check it  from [HERE](https://github.com/Aniskonig/ViewPagerwithSwipeAnimationinAndroid.git) ( the problem has been fixed by @advice-dog , it has been added to the this project)

**in layout of the ViewPager I have :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bg2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme"
    tools:context=".License">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**in there class I have:**

```
package com.medanis.fneclis


import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_license.*


class License : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_license)
        val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = CustomPagerAdapter(this)

    }
}
```

**in the first PAGE of the ViewPager where I have the button Home:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/l1_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fneclis_l1_bg"
    tools:context=".AllButtons">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Home"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="523dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="312dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="312dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

which is related to the class AllButtons (I want to use it in the most pages of the ViewPage but not all of them):

```
package com.medanis.fneclis

import android.content.Intent 
import android.os.Bundle 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity 
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_l1_page.*

class AllButtons: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_l1_page)

// those are some other pages which contains the same button and they are inside the ViewPager
           /* setContentView(R.layout.activity_l2_page)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_l3_page)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_m1page)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_m2page)*/

        Home.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } }
```

THe ADAPTER :

```
package com.medanis.fneclis

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class CustomPagerAdapter(private val mContext: Context) : PagerAdapter() {

    override fun instantiateItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position]
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
        val viewGroup = inflater.inflate(modelObject.titleResId, collection, false) as ViewGroup
        collection.addView(viewGroup)
        return viewGroup
    }

    override fun destroyItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int, view: Any) {
        collection.removeView(view as View)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return ModelObject.values().size
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {

        return view === `object`
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        val customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position]
        return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.titleResId)
    }

    override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
        return super.getItemPosition(`object`)
    }
}
```

ModelObject :

```
package com.medanis.fneclis

enum class ModelObject private constructor(val titleResId: Int ) {

    LICENSEONE(R.layout.activity_l1_page),
    PAGEONE(R.layout.activity_l1s1page),
    PAGETWO(R.layout.activity_l1s2page),

    LICENSETWO(R.layout.activity_l2_page),
    PAGETHREE(R.layout.activity_l2_s3page),
    PAGEFOUR(R.layout.activity_l2_s4page),

    LICENSETHREE(R.layout.activity_l3_page),
    PAGEFIVE(R.layout.activity_l3_s5page),
    PAGESIX(R.layout.activity_l3_s6page),

}
```

Comment: How are you using your `AllButtons` class? It seems like you're just building a `View` within your `Adapter`, but not using the `AllButtons` class.

Comment: i'm beginner please tell me what to do ?

Comment: Give me a few mins.

Comment: take your time please just don't forget me ^_^

Comment: Did those answers help you?

Comment: i tried the two solutions and they give me a lot of errors

Comment: i added a sample of the project to github please check it @Advice-Dog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code a bit, I'll explain some tips and suggestions on how to improve.

First, always add `Actvitiy` or `Fragment` to the end of your `Activities` or `Fragments`, this will help make things a lot easier to understand.

```
class LicenseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_license)

        // You can simply use the id of the View here.
        view_pager.adapter = CustomPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    }
}
```

Next, I changed your `AllButtons` `Activity` into a `Fragment`.

This code is a bit more complex, but it's using a very common pattern, the `newInstance` pattern. To create a new `Fragment`, you want to make a static method that will return a `Fragment` with your values passed into the `arguments`.

So, to explain it a bit more. You make a function called `newInstance` that takes the information this `Fragment` should be aware of, in this case, the layout we want it to show.

Next, you create a `Bundle`, and put the layout into it.

And then lastly you assign your `Fragment`'s arguments to the `Bundle`.

This is the safest way to create `Fragments`.

```
class AllButtonsFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        private const val EXTRA_COLOR = "EXTRA_COLOR"
        private const val EXTRA_LAYOUT = "EXTRA_LAYOUT"

        fun newInstance(modelObject: ModelObject): Fragment {
            val fragment = AllButtonsFragment()

            // Creating a Bundle with the various values we want to pass, such as the color and layout.
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt(EXTRA_COLOR, modelObject.titleResId)
            bundle.putInt(EXTRA_LAYOUT, modelObject.layoutResId)
            fragment.arguments = bundle

            return fragment
        }
    }

    // Getting the layout from the arguments to inflate the View.
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val layout = arguments?.getInt(EXTRA_LAYOUT)
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("arguments does not contain a layout.")
        return inflater.inflate(layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val color = arguments?.getInt(EXTRA_COLOR)
        // TODO: Do whatever with your colour.

        // Using findViewById since this isn't on every layout.
        view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.Home)?.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I rewrote your `Adapter` to work with `Fragments`. This will just get the position of the page, pass it to our `newInstance` function, and get a `Fragment` for you.

```
class CustomPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        val modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position]
        // Creating a new instance of our Fragment with this Model Object.
        return AllButtonsFragment.newInstance(modelObject)
    }

    override fun getCount() = ModelObject.values().size
}
```

Comment: it give me an error on the AllButtonFragment in :         return setContentView(layout)

Comment: and in Intent()

Comment: i added a sample of the project to github please check it

Comment: Ok, I made a few mistakes. I fixed them up, and I even make a pull request for your repo with the changes. It should now all work. I've updated my answer to reflect those code changes.

Comment: thank you i'll check it tomorrow and tell you what's happen ^_^ thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First of all you aren't using the `AllButtons` activity in your view pager, you're just using the layout and inflating it on the `CustomPagerAdapter` and since you're not using the activity, the click listener on the home button is not set.

- A couple of important thing to know. Go through the android [view pager documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral). As you can see on that page you can only add fragments to a view pager. So you need to convert your `AllButtons` to a `Fragment`. Then set the click listener on the `onViewCreated` method of the `Fragment`.

  ```
  class AllButtonsFragment: Fragment() { 
       override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
          val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_l1_page, container, false)

          return root
       }

       override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
          home.setOnClickListener {
              val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
              startActivity(intent)
          }
       }
  }
  ```

And then on your view pager adapter create an instance of the fragment (achieve this by creating a static function on the `Fragment` called `newInstance()` for a good practise) and return the appropriate fragment on the `instantiateItem` function depending on the position.

```
    override fun instantiateItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {

         return when (position) {
             0 -> A_FUNCTION.newInstance()
             1 -> B_FUNCTION.newInstance()
             else -> C_FUNCTION.newInstance()
         }
    }
```

Comment: it give me an error on A_function / b_Function and C_Function

Comment: i added a sample of the project to github please check it